# Show Angular UI Modal one second after opened

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfsRR83RjsXed45qwvbb?p=preview) I have an Angular UI modal that, when opened, it should be hidden for one second and then displayed. I use `ng-show` in the template itself, but that hides the contents, not the modal. How to hide the modal? Note that the modal is displayed right after `console.log("opened")` without waiting for `console.log("displayed")`.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function () {});

app.directive("theModal", function($uibModal,$timeout) {
          return {
            restrict: "AE",        
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                    scope.show = false;
                    console.log("opened");
                    scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
                        windowClass: 'app-modal',
                        template: '<div ng-show="show">MODAL WAS LOADED</div>'
                    });

                    $timeout(function(){
                      scope.show = true;
                      console.log("displayed");
                    },1000)

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ctl', function () {});

app.directive("theModal", function($uibModal,$timeout) {
      return {
        restrict: "AE",        
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                console.log("opened");

                $timeout(function(){
                  scope.instance = $uibModal.open({
                    windowClass: 'app-modal',
                    template: '<div >MODAL WAS LOADED</div>'
                  });
                  console.log("displayed");
                },1000)

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work in my case, in the question I used the timeout as a function that finishes in the future, but in my real scenario it's not a timeout, it's a different function. I need to wait until this function ends and only then set the show flag as true.

Comment: `..and only then set the..`, use a promise

Comment: @svarog yes, I could use a promise, however I still need to set the `show/hide` flag at the modal level and not at the content level, that's the main difficulty.